# Вывести значения свойста Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент календаря

```
<script>
import DatePick from 'vue-date-pick';
import 'vue-date-pick/dist/vueDatePick.css';

export default {
    components: {DatePick},
    data: () => ({
        date: '2019-01-01'
    })
};
</script>
```

И я его использую в другом компоненте подключая

```
<template>
  <div>
      <calendar></calendar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Calendar from './Calendar.vue';
</script>
```

Все успешно работает, только как в родительском компоненте вывести значение `v-model="date"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь подойдет событийная модель.
В дочернем компоненте генерируешь событие. Например при изменении даты.

```
this.$emit('onChangeDate', this.date);
```

В родительском компоненте подписываешься на изменения из компонента:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <calendar @onChangeDate="onChangeDate"></calendar>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import DatePick from 'vue-date-pick';
import 'vue-date-pick/dist/vueDatePick.css';

export default {
   methods: {
       onChangeDate(date){
          console.log('date from child component: ', date);
       }
   }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Подскажите пытаюсь в дочернем компоненте <date-pick v-model="date" @blur="onChangeDate"></date-pick>, но он ни как не реагирует на это событие

Comment: Похоже тебе нужно именно это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974289/how-to-use-onfocusout-function-in-vue-js .